# Remove Tax & Shipping from this success.phtml code :(

Tags: php, code

Is it possible to make the TransactionAmount to excl tax and shipping?

Please help have been trying for too long.

```
class TradeTrackerConversion
{
    /*public function __construct(array $orderData = array(), $campaignID = null, $productID = null){
        foreach ($orderData as $order)
            $this->_registerTransaction($order, $campaignID, $productID);
    }*/
    public function __construct(array $orderData = array(), $campaignID = null, $productID = null){

        $orderId = 0;
        $transactionAmount = 0.00;
        $description = 'SKU: ';

        foreach ($orderData as $order){
            if (empty($order))return;
            $transactionID = $order->getData('order_id');
            //$transactionAmount += $order->getData('price');
            $description .= $order->getData('sku').' | ';
        }

        $transactionAmount = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($transactionID)->getData('grand_total');

        $description =  substr($description, 0, -2);
        $this->_registerNewTransaction($transactionID,$transactionAmount,$description, $campaignID, $productID);
    }

    private function _registerNewTransaction($transactionID,$transactionAmount,$description, $cid, $pid)
    {
        //if (empty($order))
        //  return;

        //$transactionID = $order->getData('order_id');

        //$transactionAmount = $order->getData('price');

        //$description = 'SKU: ' . $order->getData('sku') . ' | Product name: ' .  $productName = $order->getData('name');

        echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\"><!-- // --><![CDATA[
            var ttConversionOptions = {
                type: 'sales',
                campaignID: '", htmlspecialchars($cid), "',
                productID: '", htmlspecialchars($pid), "',
                transactionID: '", htmlspecialchars($transactionID), "',
                transactionAmount: '", htmlspecialchars($transactionAmount), "',
                quantity: '1',
                email: '',
                descrMerchant: '", htmlspecialchars($description), "',
                descrAffiliate: '", htmlspecialchars($description), "',
                currency: ''
            };

        document.write('<' + 'script src=\"' + document.location.protocol + '//tm.tradetracker.net/conversion?s=", urlencode($cid), "&t=m\" type=\"text/javascript\"><' + '/script>');

        // ]]></script>

        <noscript>
            <img src=\"https://ts.tradetracker.net/?cid=", urlencode($cid), "&amp;pid=", urlencode($pid), "&amp;tid=", urlencode($transactionID), "&amp;tam=", urlencode($transactionAmount), "&amp;data=&amp;qty=1&amp;eml=&amp;descrMerchant=", urlencode($description), "&amp;descrAffiliate=", urlencode($description), "&amp;event=sales\" alt=\"\" style=\"width: 1px; height: 1px; border: 0px;\" />
        </noscript>", PHP_EOL;
    }

    private function _registerTransaction($order, $cid, $pid)
    {
        if (empty($order))
            return;

        $transactionID = $order->getData('order_id');

        $transactionAmount = $order->getData('price');

        $description = 'SKU: ' . $order->getData('sku') . ' | Product name: ' .  $productName = $order->getData('name');

        echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\"><!-- // --><![CDATA[
            var ttConversionOptions = {
                type: 'sales',
                campaignID: '", htmlspecialchars($cid), "',
                productID: '", htmlspecialchars($pid), "',
                transactionID: '", htmlspecialchars($transactionID), "',
                transactionAmount: '", htmlspecialchars($transactionAmount), "',
                quantity: '1',
                email: '',
                descrMerchant: '", htmlspecialchars($description), "',
                descrAffiliate: '", htmlspecialchars($description), "',
                currency: ''
            };

        document.write('<' + 'script src=\"' + document.location.protocol + '//tm.tradetracker.net/conversion?s=", urlencode($cid), "&t=m\" type=\"text/javascript\"><' + '/script>');

        // ]]></script>

        <noscript>
            <img src=\"https://ts.tradetracker.net/?cid=", urlencode($cid), "&amp;pid=", urlencode($pid), "&amp;tid=", urlencode($transactionID), "&amp;tam=", urlencode($transactionAmount), "&amp;data=&amp;qty=1&amp;eml=&amp;descrMerchant=", urlencode($description), "&amp;descrAffiliate=", urlencode($description), "&amp;event=sales\" alt=\"\" style=\"width: 1px; height: 1px; border: 0px;\" />
        </noscript>", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you make the products non-taxable and make free shipping enabled

Comment: @user6451 I cant do that because this code takes the order amount and brings it to the affiliate, but I want it to bring the amount without tax and shipping costs

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print `$order->getData();` fields.
Then find the value you are interested in :
I think It is something like `$order->getBaseSubtotal();` (but I'm not sure if it include shipping amount or not).
And replace your transaction amount with it .

```
$transactionAmount = $order->getBaseSubtotal(); //Care : I'm not sure for this field , it's just an example
```

The best way to do this is to test with one order .